# Python Code: Information on Execution Trace of loops/conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, execution

I want to get the execution trace of a python function in terms of the loops and conditionals executed upon completion. However, I want to do this without instrumenting the original python function with additional parameters. For example:

```
def foo(a: int, b: int):
    while a:
        a = do_something()
        if b:
            a = do_something()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo(a, b)
```

After the execution of `foo()` I want a execution trace something like:
 `[while: true, if:false, while: true, if: true, while: false, ...]` which documents the sequence of conditional evaluations in the code. Is there any way to get this information automatically for an arbitrary python function?

I understand "Coverage" python module returns the "Branch coverage" information. But I am unsure how to use it in this context?

Comment: *However, I want to do this without instrumenting the original python function with additional parameters* could you elaborate on that? Because any kind of tracing will require instrumentation. Not necessarily by changing the source code of the function itself, but certainly by using Python’s built-in tracing support.

Comment: I meant, without changing the source code of the function itself. Other tracing support is fine :)

Comment: Your branch tracing requirements are not very clear, or rather I suspect you don’t fully understand the complexities involved. For example, how should compound conditions be recorded? E.g.: `if not (a or b):`. What about `elif` and `else` blocks? Are conditional expressions also branch decisions you need to track? All these issues make it hard to write a focused answer.

Comment: It could be that using `sys.set_trace()` and tracing opcodes is enough but even then understanding how if and while result in specific combinations of jumps is not trivial. So at best I can point to the docs for [`sys.set_trace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) and the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use as a starting point [trace_conditions.py](https://gist.github.com/pisarik/26db1130824d683d46cc4ea5cdfc9ac4) and modify it if needed.

#### Example

`foo` function that defined in the question is used in the example below:

```
from trace_conditions import trace_conditions

# (1) This will just print conditions
traced_foo = trace_conditions(foo)
traced_foo(a, b)
# while c -> True
# if d -> True
# ...

# (2) This will return conditions
traced_foo = trace_conditions(foo, return_conditions=True)
result, conditions = traced_foo(a, b)
# conditions = [('while', 'c', True), ('if', 'd', True), ...)]
```

**Note**: `ast.unparse` is used to get string representation of condition. It was introduced in Python 3.9. If you want to use older version of Python, perhaps you will want to install 3rd party package [astunparse](https://pypi.org/project/astunparse/) and then use it in function [_condition_to_string](https://gist.github.com/pisarik/26db1130824d683d46cc4ea5cdfc9ac4#file-trace_conditions-py-L103). Otherwise `trace_conditions` will not return string representation of conditions.

## TL;DR

### Idea

Basically, we want to programmatically add catchers to the function's code. For example, `print` catchers could look like this:

```
while x > 5:
    print('while x > 5', x > 5)  # <-- print condition after while
    # do smth

print('if x > 5', x > 5)  # <-- print condition before if
if x > 5:
    # do smth
```

So, the main idea is to use code introspection tools in python ([inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html), [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)).

### Implementation

Here I will briefly explain the code in [trace_conditions.py](https://gist.github.com/pisarik/26db1130824d683d46cc4ea5cdfc9ac4):

#### Main function `trace_conditions`

The main function is self-explanatory and simply reflects the whole algorithm: (1) build syntactic tree; (2) inject condition catchers; (3) compile new function.

```
def trace_conditions(
        func: Callable, return_conditions=False):
    catcher_type = 'yield' if return_conditions else 'print'

    tree = _build_syntactic_tree(func)
    _inject_catchers(tree, catcher_type)
    func = _compile_function(tree, globals_=inspect.stack()[1][0].f_globals)

    if return_conditions:
        func = _gather_conditions(func)
    return func
```

The only thing that requires explanation is `globals_=inspect.stack()[1][0].f_globals`. In order to compile a new function we need to give python all modules that are used by that function (for example, it may use `math`, `numpy`, `django`, etc...). And `inspect.stack()[1][0].f_globals` simply takes everything what imported in the module of the calling function.

**Caveat!**

```
# math_pi.py
import math

def get_pi():
   return math.pi


# test.py
from math_pi import get_pi
from trace_conditions import trace_conditions

traced = trace_conditions(get_pi)
traced()  # Error! Math is not imported in this module
```

To solve it you can either modify code in `trace_conditions.py` or just add `import math` in `test.py`

#### _build_syntactic_tree

Here we are first getting the source code of function using [inspect.getsource](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) and then parse it in syntactic tree using [ast.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse). Unfortunately, python cannot inspect source code of function if it is called from `decorator`, so it seems with this approach it is not possible to use convenient decorators.

#### _inject_catchers

In this function we traverse given syntactic tree, find `while` and `if` statements and then inject catchers before or after them. `ast` module has method [walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.walk), but it returns only node itself (without parent), so I implemented slightly changed version of `walk` that returns parent node as well. We need to know parent if we want to insert catcher before `if`.

```
def _inject_catchers(tree, catcher_type):
    for parent, node in _walk_with_parent(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.While):
            _catch_after_while(node, _create_catcher(node, catcher_type))
        elif isinstance(node, ast.If):
            _catch_before_if(parent, node, _create_catcher(node, catcher_type))
    ast.fix_missing_locations(tree)
```

At the end we call `ast.fix_missing_locations` function that helps to fill in correctly technical fields like `lineno` and others that required in order to compile code. Usually, you need to use it, when you modify syntactic tree.

#### Catching `elif` statement

The funny stuff is that python doesn't have in its ast grammar `elif` statement, so it has just `if-else` statements. The `ast.If` node has field `body` that contains expressions of `if` body and field `orelse` that contains expressions of `else` block. And `elif` case is simply represented by `ast.If` node inside `orelse` field. This fact reflected in the function [_catch_before_if](https://gist.github.com/pisarik/26db1130824d683d46cc4ea5cdfc9ac4#file-trace_conditions-py-L60).

#### Catchers (and `_gather_conditions`)

There are several ways how you could catch conditions, the most simple is to just `print` it, but this approach will not work if you want handle them later in python code. One straightforward way is to have a global empty list in which you will append condition and its value during execution of function. However, I think that this solution introduces a new name in the namespace that potentially can clutter with local names inside a function, so I decided that it should be more safe to `yield` conditions and its information.

The function `_gather_conditions` is adding a wrapper around function with injected `yield` statements, that simply gathers all yielded conditions and returns result of function and conditions.